# Exchange 2010 Where did import go

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, import

I see a ton on articles on importing PST files in Exchange 2010, but I do not have the option. I need to import PST files, can anyone shed some light.

I added the administrator to the “Mailbox Import Export” role using the following at the exchange management shell.

```
New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Role “Mailbox Import Export” –User “administrator”
```

I installed Outlook as recommended [here](http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/exporting-importing-mailboxes-exchange-server-2010.html), but I only get export option in the Exchange Management Console and trying to run the import from the exchange management shell only gives error saying cmdlet mot found.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I needed to have both Outlook 64bit, 32bit will not work. I also needed to assign a role to my user:

`New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Role “Mailbox Import Export” –User “USER”`

I found the solution [here](http://www.howexchangeworks.com/2009/08/where-is-exportimport-cmdlets-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

you have to run special version of power shell - [exchange management powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123778.aspx). for starters - you'll find it in your start menu in *microsoft exchange server 2010* folder.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I am using the exchange management shell. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need permissions to perform the import process through the **Desktop Outlook Application**. But if you are to perform the process through Exchange Management Shell, then you need to provide the permission to perform Import process. For that execute the following command

**New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Role “Mailbox Import Export” –User {username}**

In the above command, **username** stands for user asking for Import permission.

For Ex: **New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Role “Mailbox Import Export” –User Administrator**

Then, for Import, execute the below command

**New-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox “User_Mailbox_Name” -FilePath “UNC_shared_File_Path”**

**Note**: **User_Mailbox_Name** is the name of the User mailbox to whom the resultant PST file will be imported to. **UNC shared File Path** is different from the Normal File Path. If you don't know how to create UNC shared File Path, Refer: **[Creating UNC shared file path for a PST file](https://www.edbtopstoutlook.com/blog/2010/import-pst-to-mailbox-via-powershell.html)**

Follow below steps to Import PST files to Exchange server through Desktop Outlook Application

1. Launch **Desktop Outlook Application**.
2. Go to **File**>> **Open & Export**>> **Import/Export**.
3. Select **Import** option as per your Requirement.
4. Select File type to Import (**.pst** format, in your case).
5. Select **Folder** to Import PST file

**Note**: Provide option to where to place the imported PST file

**-In Current Folder**

**-Into Same Folder**

Your selected files will be imported to the destination Mailbox folder.